# Linq Contains string comma not getting results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I would like to filter out my result base on roleIds. I have a multi select UI that is creating a comma separated string. I have a store stored procedure that is doing the same. In the linq I am creating a list of strings and using `Contains` but I am not getting any results. I see there is a user with that role but when I go into the if statement all the results are removed.

sp

```
RolesIds = STUFF((select ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),i.ItemDictionaryId)
                        FROM dbo.ItemDictionary i
                        JOIN GroupMemberRoleXref gmrx ON gmrx.RoleId = i.ItemDictionaryId
                        join GroupMemberLog gml on gml.GroupMemberLogId =  gmrx.GroupMemberLogId    
                        where gml.CustomerId = c.CustomerId and gml.GroupId = @GroupId 
                        and (gmrx.EndDate >=  md.StartDAte OR gmrx.EndDate IS NULL) and gmrx.StartDate <= md.StartDAte
                        FOR 
                            XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
```

EF Model

```
public string RolesIds { get; set; }
```

Service

```
    List<string> rolesList = roleIds.Split(',').ToList();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleIds))
    {
        usersResult= usersResult.Where(x => rolesList.Contains(x.RolesIds)).ToList();
    }
```

I have added the stored procedure and the EF Model. In my Repository I call this stored procedure and it is mapped to this EF Model RolesIds. I then I have a UI that is a MultiSelect control. The UI will send the ids in a comma separated string. I then convert that into  rolesList and try to filter out the data. So if the user select member that has a role id of 33 It will only return the users that have that role.

This looks to be working

```
List<string> rolesList = roleIds.Split(',').ToList();

            //extra filter
            if (rolesList.Count > 0)
            {
                usersResult= usersResult.Where(x => rolesList.Any(y => x.RoleIds.Contains(y))).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Is `x.RolesIds` a collection or a single value? If it's a comma-separated list of IDs you're going to have a hard time translating that to SQL

Comment: its a collection in SQL I am doing this  `STUFF((select ', ' + i.RoleId`

Comment: SIde note: Your condition `(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleIds))` is likely not giving you what you indend. You loght want either (1) `(roleIds.Count > 0)` together with an option to eliminate blank values in the first line of your code, or (2)  or something like `(roleids.Any(id => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)))`.

Comment: Another question that you need to ask: Are you looking for users where (1) RolesIds equals rolesList, (2) RolesIds is a superset of rolesList, (3) rolesList is a superset of RolesIds, or (4) RolesIds intersect rolesList is non-empty?

Comment: So to be clear - you have separate tables for users and roles, you are creating a comma separated string with a list of roles, and you want to see if that list contains one or more values from a list of values? There's a better way to do that.

Comment: Your code seems very confusing.  From what I read, you have a string like `"id1, id2"` named `roleIds`.  You split that into a list named `rolesList`.  They you have a variable (named `usersResult`) typed as a collection some type and that type has a mostly unrelated property named `RoleIds` (type unknown).  Can you show the types of your variables and describe what you are trying to do?  The comments so far indicate that folks are a bit confused by your code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I added more information to help

Comment: Beware that the `Contains` function in your updated condition `rolesList.Any(y => x.RoleIds.Contains(y))` is probably doing a string search, so something like `"11111,22222,33333".Contains("222")` will yield true. You may need to do something klugy like `rolesList.Any(y => ("," + x.RoleIds + ",").Contains(", " + y + ","))`. Also, your for-xml-path concatenation uses comma+space as a separator, but only trims the leading comma (leaving a space). Suggest either drop the space or change the `STUFF( ..., 1, 1, '')` to `STUFF( ..., 1, 2, '')` and then tweak the condition to match.